# How to get ERD in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I am using Teradata via Sql Assistant. When I want to look up a relationship between two table I do the following : `show table table1` and can see the `create` statement that generated the table with all primary and foreign keys. However, this is not very convenient because I might be missing something. So, is there any way to get the Entity Relationship Diagram ? I am interested in about 20 tables. So, how can I get relationships between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Assistant does not show relationships between objects through version 14.x. In my experience with Teradata, relationships have been modeled in proper modeling tools.

If your environment is enforcing referential integrity there are views in the DBC database that could be queried in SQL Assistant to help show you the relationships. However, the results would be in tabular form like any other query against the database.

- DBC.All_RI_Children
- DBC.All_RI_Parents
- DBC.RI_Child_Tables
- DBC.RI_Distinct_Children
- DBC.RI_Distinct_Parents
- DBC.RI_Parent_Tables
- DBC.Tables2